# How can I position a child div at the right upper of the parent?

Tags: css

How can I position a child div at the right upper corner of the parent div and allow it to be on top of any other thing in terms of zindex so it does not push anything out?

I'm trying to show a message on hover of a parent.

This is what I have so far: http://pastebin.com/svAWeGQS

but it has set margin, whereas I want it to start where parent ends.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best approach is an absolute position:

```
div.parent {
    position: relative;
}

div.child {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    left: auto;
    z-index: 100;
    display: none;
}
```

Then change `child`'s `display` to `block` to show the child div.

Comment: You may also want to add `left: auto;` to the `.child` element to override any other `left` styles that might exist.

Comment: I dont think I explained it well. I need to have child to appear not a set distance from parent but right where parent ends. so based on parents lengths, all children would appear at different position in terms of x axis.

Comment: Now i don't think I understand fully. With absolute position you can set exactly where a child would appear by using properties left, right, top and bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed your code based on your pastebin.. here's a fiddle.. hope this is what you were looking for.. http://jsfiddle.net/jNUKq/1/

Comment: It's always a good idea to put the actual answer and altered code here, for posterity -- we can't guarantee that jsFiddle or pastebin will exist for as long as this question does.